# Swift delegation and storyboard @IBDesignable issue

Tags: swift

Below is just a test of delegation.

What I did was, 1) draw a rectangle, 2) set this rectangle's width of line with a delegate, 3) Hope the storyboard could update its display.

There are two questions:

The first is: If I use "`testView.widthdelegate = ViewController()`" rather than "`testView.widthdelegate = self`" , the "`var widthValue: CGFloat? = widthdelegate?.trueWidth`" will be nil, but it should be 50, what's different between "self" and "`ViewController()`"?

The second is: I still want to update the result of draw in storyboard, where you can see I did a `SetNeedDisplay()` but no use at all, how could I do it?

**View**

```
import UIKit

protocol widthDelegate: class {
var trueWidth: CGFloat { get }
}

@IBDesignable
class TestView: UIView {

weak var widthdelegate: widthDelegate?

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    var widthValue: CGFloat? = widthdelegate?.trueWidth ?? 1.0
    rectangle(widthRefer: widthValue!)
    println("width in TestView is \(widthdelegate?.trueWidth)" )

}

func rectangle(#widthRefer: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath{
    var rect = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: bounds.width/2-50, y: bounds.height/2-50, width: 100, height: 100))
    rect.lineWidth = widthRefer
    rect.stroke()
    return rect
 }
}
```

**Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,widthDelegate {

var trueWidth: CGFloat = 50


@IBOutlet var testView: TestView!{
    didSet{ //after the storyboard loaded.

//        testView.widthdelegate = ViewController()
    testView.widthdelegate = self
    testView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1:

`self` is the actual instance of the class the code is in (correct solution)

`ViewController()` creates a brand new instance of ViewController which is not identical with the instance created in IB (wrong solution)

Answer 2:

Never implement `didSet` for an IBOutlet because it's never called during initialization. Better use `viewDidLoad()` for settings

Some other notes:

Please consider the naming convention that class, protocol and enum names start with a capital letter.

The `class` constraint in the protocol declaration is not needed